# Set border for entire row when selected in TreeList DevExpress

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

I have the following problem. I wish that the dotted border around a selected NodeCell in my TreeList wrap the entire row rather than the cell I click on. The selection of the row is good (i.e., the whole row gets selected no matter which cell is focused), however I wish the border would highlight the full row rather than just a particular cell within that row when clicking on it. I already set:

```
treeList.OptionsSelection.EnableAppearanceFocusedCell = false;
```

But it seems I need a property for TreeList which is similar to the one for GridView, such as:

```
gridView1.FocusRectStyle = DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.DrawFocusRectStyle.RowFocus;
```

I attached a screenshot to exemplify:

[image]

The selected row is highlighted (correctly) in blue, but the border highlights a particular cell, although the entire row is in fact selected. I wish that the border wrapps the entire row, not just one cell.

Answer (score 1):

As from [DevExpress support forum](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T124910) - there is no equivalent of `FocusRectStyle` in XtraTree in present time.

However, if you need that dotted border - you can draw it by yourself.

First, set `treeList.OptionsSelection.EnableAppearanceFocusedCell = false;`

Next, define pen with you want to draw your border somewhere in your class:

```
private readonly Pen _PenBorder = new Pen(Color.Black) {DashStyle = DashStyle.Dot};
```

and finally, handle `treeList.CustomDrawNodeCell` event by something like this:

```
void TreeListCustomDrawNodeCell(object sender, CustomDrawNodeCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Node.Focused)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(_PenBorder, e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top, e.Bounds.Right, e.Bounds.Top);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(_PenBorder, e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Bottom - 1, e.Bounds.Right, e.Bounds.Bottom - 1);

        if (e.Column.VisibleIndex == 0)
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(_PenBorder, e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top, e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Bottom);

        if (e.Column.VisibleIndex == treeList.VisibleColumns.Count - 1)
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(_PenBorder, e.Bounds.Right - 1, e.Bounds.Top, e.Bounds.Right - 1, e.Bounds.Bottom);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured that would be a solution, but I was hoping for something "cheaper". Anyway, thanks for the suggestion, I'll try it and see how it goes